# A splash page on landing page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, homepage

I want to create a splash page with a timer which disappears after 5 seconds when I open up the website before it opens up the main homepage. Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks n advance

Answer (score 1):

I would propose first to make this at the front end. The reason is Google and other crawlers can read your content and don't penalize you for sneaky (the user didn't expect a redirect) redirects or slow loading times.

What I would do:
On the main page :

```
function load_splash() {
 setTimeout(function () {
   $('#hiddendiv').hide();
 }, 5000);
}
```

Now the load_splash can be called when the document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   load_splash( );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The splash page is easy enough, that's in about half of all themes these days. To make it disappear, I would create a second page to be the real homepage and send the browser there from the splash page after five seconds.

Ideally, I'd do that by putting a `header('refresh:5;url=/realhomepage/');` somewhere early in the splash page's code, but I haven't found that easy in WP - remember that it must be sent before you do *any* HTML output. Alternatively, you can put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/realhomepage/">` in the HTML header, which is easier but still ugly because you need to put a special case in `header.php`. In the end, I'd probably hack it by putting

```
sleep(5);
wp_redirect('/realhomepage/');
exit();
```

near the end of the splash page code.

Also, speaking as a user rather than a programmer, I really, really wouldn't do this in the first place. Having to wait before I can use your site's functionality is a very good reason for me not to bother and to go to the competition instead.